# Project 'Pods' - Turn on Whole Module Optimization

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode9

In Xcode 9 I'm getting the following suggestion for a cocoa pods project:
[image: suggestion]

What does it do? And, shall I turn it on, or it will break things up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Using Whole Module Optimization allows the compiler to look at all the
>   source files in a module. This make compilation slower but allows it
>   to optimize generic functions even when they are in separate source
>   files. You can see this in the final test run where the execution time
>   is now the same for both the local and external function definitions.
>
> In summary, if you don’t mind the extra compilation time try turning
>   on Whole Module Optimization for your release builds.

This [source](https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/) should give you more insights into the **Whole-module optimization**

Any changes to the Pods project that Xcode makes will be blown away next time you run `pod install` so the update will have to happen within Cocoapods to get rid of this warning. There is a discussion about this [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4439).

The shorter-term solution is to add a `post_install` script as [Mike suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48550610/215748).

Answer (score 24):

You can have this automatically enabled each time you run `pods install` by adding the below `post_install` script to the end of your `Podfile`.

```rb
post_install do |installer| 
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    if config.name == 'Release'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'] = 'wholemodule'
    end    
  end
end
```

In older versions of Xcode you will need:

```rb
post_install do |installer| 
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    if config.name == 'Release'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Owholemodule'
    else
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
    end    
  end
end
```